# xslt: value of text associated with element

Tags: xml, xslt

If I have an XML file that includes

```
<param name="foo" value="5000" >foo is a way of making pasta sauce</param>
<param name="bar" value="3000" >bar is controlling the beer taps</param>
```

and I want to use XSLT to process this into an HTML file, with the name and value attributes and the text as a description, how can I get the XML node text?

```
<xsl:for-each select="param">
   <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></td>
      <td><xsl:text> </xsl:text></td>
   </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The above XSLT fragment does successfully get the name and value attributes, but it fails to get the text, and I think I'm missing something obvious but I don't know what.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this

```
<xsl:for-each select="param">
   <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
   </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 5):

aha, this also seems to work:

```
<xsl:for-each select="param">
   <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
   </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Yes. And the diference is: `xsl:value-of select="text()"` output the string value of the first text node child, and `xsl:value-of select="."` output the context node' string value.