# targeting attributes that are vegetarian with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Hey guys I'm working on my first project with xml and xslt. Now what I'm trying to do to finish up is target the attributes that are for the vegetarian menus and display them on bottom of page under name of restaurants. I need the name of the MenuItem, Price, and Calories to be displayed on one line. Any help would be appreciated.

ok i've got it all exept at bottom of page i should have

Little Cabin Inn

Menu Item Price Calories                                                                                               Fruit Salad 5.50 <300

Ma and Pa's

Menu Item Price Calories                                                                                                          Chef salad 5.00 200

Here is XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Kenny Freeman-->
<Restaurants>
<Restaurant Name="Little Cabin Inn" QualityRating="3" PriceRating="2">
<Location>
  <Address>10 Main Street</Address>
  <City>Chicago</City>
  <State>Illinois</State>
</Location>

<PhoneNumber>555-555-5555</PhoneNumber>

<Menu>
  <MenuItem Price="4.95" Calories="450"  IsVegetarian="false">Hamburger</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem Price="5.50" Calories="&lt;300" IsVegetarian="true">Fruit Salad</MenuItem>
</Menu>
</Restaurant>

<Restaurant Name="Ma and Pa" QualityRating="4" PriceRating="3">
<Location>
  <Address>1234 2nd Street</Address>
  <City>Chicago</City>
  <State>Illinois</State>
</Location>

<PhoneNumber>444-444-4444</PhoneNumber>
<Menu>
<MenuItem Price="4.00" Calories="475" IsVegetarian="false">CheeseBurger</MenuItem>
<MenuItem Price="5.00" Calories="200" IsVegetarian="true">Chef  Salad</MenuItem>
</Menu>
</Restaurant>

<Restaurant Name="Meaty Petes Cafe" QualityRating="4" PriceRating="1">
<Location>
  <Address>1232 Cedar Drive</Address>
  <City>Los Angelas</City>
  <State>California</State>
</Location>

<PhoneNumber>333-333-3333</PhoneNumber>
<Menu>
  <MenuItem Price="6.00" Calories="500" IsVegetarian="false">Stack of Ribs</MenuItem>
</Menu>
</Restaurant>
</Restaurants>
```

And the XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="html" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Restaurants</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Recommended Restaurant</h1>
    <p>
      In Chicago, I recommend <xsl:value-of select="Restaurants/Restaurant/@Name" />
    </p>
    <h1>Restaurants by location</h1>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Restaurant Name</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Quality</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="Restaurants/Restaurant">
        <xsl:sort select="Location/State"/>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Location/City"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Location/State"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:for-each select="Restaurants/Restaurant"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="@QualityRating"/>
          </td>
          <td>
        <xsl:for-each select="Restaurants/Restaurant"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@PriceRating"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  <!--Restaurants that serve vegetarian-->
    <h1>Restaurants with Vegetarian Choices</h1>
  <xsl:for-each select="Restaurants/Restaurant">
  <xsl:if test="Menu/MenuItem/@IsVegetarian='true'">
    <h3>
  <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="Menu/MenuItem">
        <br>
          <xsl:value-of select="Menu/MenuItem"/>

            <xsl:value-of select="@Price"/>


            <xsl:value-of select="@Calories"/>

        </br>

      </xsl:for-each>

  </h3>

  </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please show your expected output.

Comment: Um - no. You have a sample input document, an XSLT 1.0 transform, and a prose description of output, but no listing of an output document. Please show your expected output, for the sample input, as a html document (meaning a code listing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XSLT 1.0 stylesheet ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Restaurants</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Recommended Restaurant</h1>
    <p>
      In Chicago, I recommend <xsl:value-of select="
        Restaurants/Restaurant[Location/City='Chicago'][1]/@Name" />
      <!-- Assume that restaurants are sorted by recommendation. -->
    </p>
    <h1>Restaurants by location</h1>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Restaurant Name</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Quality</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Restaurants/Restaurant">
        <xsl:sort select="Location/State" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </table>

    <!--Restaurants that serve vegetarian-->
    <h1>Restaurants with Vegetarian Choices</h1>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Restaurant Name</th>
        <th>Menu item</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Calories</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Restaurants/Restaurant/Menu/MenuItem[@IsVegetarian='true']">
        <xsl:sort select="Location/State" />
        <xsl:sort select="@Name" />
        <xsl:sort select="text()" />        
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Restaurant">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@Name" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="Location/City" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="Location/State" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@QualityRating" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@PriceRating" /></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MenuItem">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="../../@Name" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@Price" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@Calories" /></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... will transform this input document ...

```
<Restaurants>
    <Restaurant Name="Little Cabin Inn" QualityRating="3" PriceRating="2">
        <Location>
            <Address>10 Main Street</Address>
            <City>Chicago</City>
            <State>Illinois</State>
        </Location>
        <PhoneNumber>555-555-5555</PhoneNumber>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Price="4.95" Calories="450" IsVegetarian="false">Hamburger</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Price="5.50" Calories="&lt;300" IsVegetarian="true">Fruit Salad</MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Restaurant>
    <Restaurant Name="Ma and Pa" QualityRating="4" PriceRating="3">
        <Location>
            <Address>1234 2nd Street</Address>
            <City>Chicago</City>
            <State>Illinois</State>
        </Location>
        <PhoneNumber>444-444-4444</PhoneNumber>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Price="4.00" Calories="475" IsVegetarian="false">CheeseBurger</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Price="5.00" Calories="200" IsVegetarian="true">Chef  Salad</MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Restaurant>
    <Restaurant Name="Meaty Petes Cafe" QualityRating="4" PriceRating="1">
        <Location>
            <Address>1232 Cedar Drive</Address>
            <City>Los Angelas</City>
            <State>California</State>
        </Location>
        <PhoneNumber>333-333-3333</PhoneNumber>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Price="6.00" Calories="500" IsVegetarian="false">Stack of Ribs</MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Restaurant>
</Restaurants>
```

... into this output document ...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Restaurants</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Recommended Restaurant</h1>
    <p>
      In Chicago, I recommend Little Cabin Inn</p>
    <h1>Restaurants by location</h1>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Restaurant Name</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Quality</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Meaty Petes Cafe</td>
        <td>Los Angelas</td>
        <td>California</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Little Cabin Inn</td>
        <td>Chicago</td>
        <td>Illinois</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ma and Pa</td>
        <td>Chicago</td>
        <td>Illinois</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <h1>Restaurants with Vegetarian Choices</h1>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Restaurant Name</th>
        <th>Menu item</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Calories</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ma and Pa</td>
        <td>Chef  Salad</td>
        <td>5.00</td>
        <td>200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Little Cabin Inn</td>
        <td>Fruit Salad</td>
        <td>5.50</td>
        <td>&lt;300</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Assumptions

1. I've had to guess the desired output because the OP did not list it. I've put all vegetarian restaurants into one table. But possible multiple tables was required?
2. I have assumed that the recommended Chicago restaurant, was the first Chicago one listed in the input document, in document order.

Comment: thanks all i needed was the bottom part for the vegetarian items and they didnt need to be in a table. but i got it thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing two things wrong.

First, the following snippet isn't going to include the text of the menu item element:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Menu/MenuItem"/>
```

You've already selected the element, so you could use something like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
```

to get the inner text - see [xslt: value of text associated with element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469371/xslt-value-of-text-associated-with-element) for more

Secondly, although you're selecting restaurants with vegetarian menu items, it sounds like you then want to only show vegetarian menu items. So you'll need to change your loop to only show those items - an extra xsl:if statement might do the job, although it might be possible to do it more cleanly.

Comment: the loop isnt working but i atleast got the text to display thanks